# Options of version control for jupyter notebook in Sourcetree?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, diff, atlassian-sourcetree

I came across the page about version control for jupyter notebook here:

https://nextjournal.com/schmudde/how-to-version-control-jupyter

Most external diff tools are used in cmd window. Does anyone know which tool can work well with Sourcetree?